# Unable to connect to S3

Tags: shell, amazon-s3, fatal-error

I am trying to write a shell script to connect to a private S3 bucket to download a few files.

aws s3 cp s3://p1-bucket/2017-09-05_metric.csv $HOME --profile p1

The above command works fine when executed on the shell. However, the same command fails when executed as a part of the script with the following error:

fatal error: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://p1-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/2017-09-05_metric.csv"

Can someone help me fix this

Comment: Can you post your script or parts of it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is being caused by the initialization of a proxy connection to $https_proxy variable and is resolved by assigning a null to $https_proxy.